# Java (Eclipse) reference to my own jar library won't resolve

Tags: java, eclipse, shared-libraries

I have an Eclipse workspace. I have two java projects at the same level below it.  One (Project A) is a a project that I uses a library and manually export to a jar file using the Eclipse UI.  The other (Project B) is a java project I intend to export as a runnable jar file with a `Main` function - essentially a sample project that uses my library.  Both use JavaSE-12 as the JRE reference.

Here is the structure:

```
    - Project A
      - com.mystuff.api (package)
        - MyAPIClass.java
      - Referenced Libraries
        - <3rd Party jar>
      - dist
        - com.mystuff.api.jar (exported library jar file)
      - module-info.java
    - Project B
      - com.mystuff.sample (package)
        - MyApp.java (Main defined here)
      - Referenced Libraries
       - ('Add Lib' Refernce to Project A/dist/com.mystuff.api.jar)
      - module-info.java
```

Now in `MyApp.java` I try to create an instance of MyAPIClass (a public class from Project A)

```
package com.mystuff.sample;

import com.mystuff.api.MyAPIClass;

public class MyApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        MyAPIClass obj = new MyAPIClass();
    }
}
```

But I get a compilation error for the import statement:

```
The type com.mystuff.api.MyAPIClass is not accessible
```

But I can browse the JAR file under Project B/Referenced libraries and see MyAPIClass!

Is there a better way to reference my library Project A jar file to make sure Project B can resolve its types?

Comment: How did you reference `com.mystuff.api.jar` in Project B? Is it by Project -> Properties -> Build path -> Add External Jar ?

Comment: Close,  Project -> Properties -> Add Jar -> Navigate to <root>/Project A/dist/com.mystyuff.api.jar

Comment: @PasupathiRajamanickam FYI, Add External Jar does not work either

Comment: Looks like everything is good but some error hidden somewhere, it will be useful if we check Window -> Show view -> Markers { java build path problems or Java problems (maybe filtering Project A or B }

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.  During the creation of both projects I chose to create `module-info.java`files in each.  I have to admit I'm pretty rusty on my java and I don't really know what these do.  I deleted both of the `module-info.java` files and the references were resolved.

Comment: Having a `module-info.java` files enables [JPMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Platform_Module_System) and your dependencies must be on the _Modulepath_ instead of on the _Classpath_ plus in the `module-info.java` you have to add a line `requires <module-name>;` to be able to access something of this module. The dependency from Project B to Project A can be specified directly in the _Java Build Path_ dialog in the tab _Projects_, without the need to create/update a JAR.

Comment: Thanks @howlger, I come from a .NET background and was struggling with the eclipse equivalent of project references.  This did the trick!